# python: csv.writer - commas between numbers in the output

Tags: python

i suspect that this is a simple answer, but i cannot figure out the answer. (I did give it due diligence)

i wrote a simple python program to identify prime numbers. the program is function, but i'm receiving strange results in the output. when i have it write a number with multiple digits, each number is comma separated; for example, 13 is added to the document as 1,3. I would like to have a comma after each full number (13,) and don't want commas within the number (1,3 or 1,301). eventually, i want to have each number on its own row (one of the issue that i ran into in my g1 program is that the row became too long around 50mill ;-)

Any thoughts?

```
#!/bin/python3

import time
import os
import csv

folderLocation = "c:/notNow/"    

primeName = "primeNumbers.csv"
# notPrimeName = "noPrimeNumbers.csv"

primePath=folderLocation + primeName
# notPrimePath=folderLocation + notPrimeName

no=13
os.makedirs(folderLocation)
f = open(primePath, "w")
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(str(no))
```

output: 1,3

Comment: "writerow" expects a sequence of items like e. g. a list or tuple. If you give it a string it is seen as sequence of characters where each character has its own cell.

Comment: Try `writer.writerow([no])` instead of `writer.writerow(str(no))`

Comment: @MichaelButscher
thank you for your note. yeah. i kept getting an error that said "iterable expected, not int" 
all the documentation that i found talked about csv writer with text outputs; so, i couldn't figure out another way to make the numbers acceptable to the function.

Comment: @RMPR
Thank you! that was the trick - thanks! what do the square brackets indicate?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Have you looked at the [documentation for `writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) ? As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, unless there is a good reason not to do so. Also, it's probably best to use a context manager to handle file objects, and use pathlib instead of the os module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`writerow` expects a sequence of items (e.g list). A string is just seen as a sequence of individual characters, try this instead:

```
writer.writerow([no])
```